# fusiontablecell object retrieve the value from kml via fusion table

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

currently I am work on the project by using polygons KML and fusion table
I  have uploading the kml into fusion table and share it, by using the mao id, in my custom web page, they are display correct, 
now I need add address search function in to custom page, my goal is display the kml polygon information and the search result information into one information window,

I could display the marker address info and I could by click to display the polygon info window, but they are separate and could not display in one inforwindow

Comment: Can you please explain: You have polygons inside the fusionTable, but where do the markers come from and where do you search for what?

Comment: sorry for confusion, in the Custom web page there is a search box for user to find a address then display the marker should display the polygon information in the same infowindows, that's the goal

Comment: and where do you search for the address? Inside the fusionTable or somewhere else?